# pass data to a page within a redirect in React but have error in when read data , How slove?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on a project , i must login after that send user to dashboard page  where I have to pass data from one page to another i have error. i can see data with React developers tools but when i try to show i i have error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"

---login--

```
 handleLogin = () => {
        axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
        let username = document.getElementById('username').value;
        let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        const querystring = require('querystring');
        axios.post('url', querystring.stringify({
            username: username, //gave the values directly for testing
            password: password,
        }))
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
                if (res.data.hasError === false) {
                    let user = res.data.result.name;     
                    this.props.history.push({
                        pathname: "/",
                       state:{
                            key:user
                       }
                    })

                } 

            }).catch((error) => {
        })
    };
```

---Header---

```
    class UserHeader extends Component {
        render() {
            return (  
<span>
       {this.props.location.state.key}
 </span>
            );
        }
    }
    export default UserHeader;
```

---index.js-----

```
const app = (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>     
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>   
            <Route  path="/" component={App}/>   
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
)

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

in Header page

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to get state from regular props, but you should get them from route props. Here is an example of how it works in my project:

```
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact render={(routeProps) => ( <BooksWrapper books={this.props.books} /> )} />
      <Route path="/edit-book" render={(routeProps) => (
         <EditBook bookInfo={routeProps.location.state.bookInfo} />
      )} />
   </Switch>
```

And then I get them like regular props.

Comment: i add index.js for route

Answer (score 1):

You can use the history methods outside of your components. 
First, npm install history and create a history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

in header.js import history.js and use

```
  <span>{history.location.state.key}</span>
```